# Can't specify type signature in GHCI when using DataKinds

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

So, ghci is giving me an interesting error when I try and pin down the type of a polymorphic return value when using `DataKinds`. I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

data DataKind
    = KindA
    | KindB

data SomeData (a :: DataKind) = forall c. SomeData
    { val :: Int
    , sub :: Maybe (SomeData c)
    }

deriving instance Show (SomeData a)

two :: SomeData 'KindA
two = SomeData 2 Nothing
```

This code compiles as expected. If I construct `SomeData` in ghci and don't specify the type it works fine:

```
> two
SomeData {val = 2, sub = Nothing}

> :t two
two :: SomeData 'KindA

> SomeData 2 Nothing
SomeData 2 Nothing :: SomeData a
```

But if I try and specify the type it errors:

```
> SomeData 2 Nothing :: SomeData 'KindA
<interactive>:745:32-37: error:
• Data constructor ‘KindA’ cannot be used here
    (Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds)
• In the first argument of ‘SomeData’, namely ‘KindA’
  In an expression type signature: SomeData KindA
  In the expression: SomeData 1 Nothing :: SomeData KindA
```

It appears that the quote is not being interpreted by ghci. I started the repl using `stack ghci`. Has anyone encountered this before? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I believe its a GHCi thing. Try writing `:set -XDataKinds` to manually enable the extension. For some reason the interpreter doesn't load it automatically when you load a file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SomeData 2 Nothing :: SomeData 'KindA` works if you first `:seti -XDataKinds`. My thought is that the pragmas in the code files are incorporated when loading the file, but for things evaluated in the REPL you need to enable them inside GHCi explicitly as well.

I would think of this as when in GHCi, the file(s) you load are more like imported modules and any code in the REPL has its own set of language extensions. When loading multiple files in GHCi, you might not necessarily want all language extensions in all loaded files to be enabled/available.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I was reading a similar question and one of the answers mentioned that you only need the DataKinds extension when you use the promoted constructors, which seems to be equivalent of needing to enable the extension in the repl.

Comment: It's often better to use `:seti` instead of `:set` – using `:set` will *also* cause extensions to be enabled in *all loaded files*, as though you'd run `ghc` with those options.  The `:seti` command just *set*s the extensions for *i*nteractive use.  For example, GHCi behaves as though the user had specified `:seti -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` by default – GHCi-bound variables aren't monomorphized, but variables bound in loaded files are left alone.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky I've edited the answer to reference `:seti`. I had not been aware of that option and looking it up I agree that its behavior would be less surprising in this case.